# background color change material design

Tags: html, css, material-design

Using material design lite i am trying to make the menu's background black and the front white.

But the background color is only becoming black just for those place where the menu have content, other places it is default color !

Have A LOOK HERE ---
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbKVko

```
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Chris</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation" id="left_menu">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Cost & Sales</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Budget</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Analysis</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>

  <style>
      #left_menu{
          background-color: black;
          color: white;
      }
  </style>
```

How can i make the whole menu's background black and the text color white !

this is my css --

```
      #left_menu{
          background-color: black;
          color: white;
      }
```

anyone knows how to solve this issue !

Comment: change the background-color of this `.mdl-layout__drawer`

Comment: @Radmation thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do.

```
.mdl-layout__drawer {
    background: #000;  
    color: #fff; // for the header of that menu
} 
.mdl-layout__drawer .mdl-navigation .mdl-navigation__link:hover {
   color: #fff; // links
}
```

Comment: No problem. :D Glad I could help!

Comment: @ChristoferHansen hey do you mind marking this as the answer that way it doesn't show up in my profile page as unanswered?